# Dropdown from Vlookup

Tags: list, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, google-sheets-formula, dropdownbox

I'm trying to make a little tool for a card game, which would allow the players to check the stats of the cards. The idea is to have three dropdowns, Name, Rarity and Variant:

[image: Columns]

[image: List of cards]

The player select their card, add the rarity and choose the version if it's variant or not. Then, a vlookup brings that card's info. The first two dropdowns are easy, the thrid one not so much. I tried using

`=IFERROR(Query('Cards'!A:E;"select E where A='"&A2&"' and C="&B2&" and D = '"&C2&"' ";0))`

but it only works if a card only has variants with different rarity. If a card has two variants with the same rarity (like Moritaka in the image) it shows both versions. I need the player to be able to choose which variant is the correct one. A vlookup checking the other two and adding the content of the Variant2   column to a dropdown would be perfect, but I can't manage to make one.

Here is the full sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tldaFq-YD5-as_1CrMBNh1i116OLO-MIl7Un_mjm0jo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I've updated the post with the sheet in case it helps.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the player [needs] to be able to choose which variant is the correct one"? So, in case of Moritaka, which would be considered the "correct one"? Also, have you considered using a script for this instead? @Xalcer

Comment: @ale13
1 - By the correct one I mean the card which they want to see the stats of.

2 - I'm farily new to scripts, so I wouldn't even know how to make one.

Comment: Why not display the stats for each variant (even though multiple are shown)? @Xalcer